# Why can´t I work with this Object outside the ngOnInit() Method?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am getting some data from my server and want to do some stuff with it inside the .ts file. It's an elementary thing that I don't understand about Typescript/angular so far...Hope someone can help me here

```
user: any;

public doStuff(){
    alert(this.user.username);
 }
```

a user is an object having different properties like 'username' that is initialized on the ngOnInit()  block.
I´m setting it in the ngOnInit method. The service is injected correctly and following code works properly

```
ngOnInit() {

this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile =>{
    this.user= profile.user;
    this.initStuff();

  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  });
 }
```

it's alerting the username as intended...but as soon as I move the method call of the doStuff() Method outside that Codeblock, it´s not working anymore, in the browser-console it says "cannot read property 'value' of undefined" - why is it undefined? If I use {{user.username}} in the component.html, it also shows me the correct username

```
ngOnInit() {

this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile =>{
    this.user= profile.user;
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  });
    this.initStuff(); // why cant i call it here? Its where I also call all of my other doStuff() methods
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because getProfile() is async operation. If you want to do stuff with server data it has to be done in subscribe next() method. Next method is called when aysnc operation has new value.

If you call initStuff() outside of next() method, it will be executed immediately that's why your getting "cannot read peoperty 'value' of undefined".

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Leave the initStuff() method call inside subscribe(), and can you explain "But how do I use the parameter 'user' from another method then?" post some examples.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood all correctly you are trying to call not yet received data and it is reason of you console error. In described function you use Observable (RxJs) and is function is async. If you want to do something with variable 'profile' you should to place operation in Observable callback, is meant in body  subscribe's call method.